# summation involving Kronecker Deltas

Tags: simplifying-expressions, symbolic, summation

I see that:

```
Sum[u[q] u[k] v[k1] v[k + k1 + q] KroneckerDelta[k1 - q], {k1, -\[Infinity], \[Infinity]}]
```

produces the correct result: `u[k] u[q] v[q] v[k + 2 q]`

However:

```
Sum[u[q] u[k] v[k1] v[k + k1 + q] KroneckerDelta[k - q], {k1, -\[Infinity], \[Infinity]}]
```

does not give

```
Sum[u[q] u[q] v[k1] v[k1+2*q], {k1, -\[Infinity], \[Infinity]}]
```

as I would like to. Can this be done?

Also, a similar thing occurs in multiple summations involving `KroneckerDelta` or `DiscreteDelta`, e.g:

```
Sum[u[q] u[k] v[k1] v[k + k1 + q] KroneckerDelta[k1 - q], 
{q, -\[Infinity], \[Infinity]}, {k,-\[Infinity], \[Infinity]}, {k1, -\[Infinity], \[Infinity]}]
```

doesn't give as output:

```
Sum[u[q] *u[k]*v[q]*v[k + 2*q] KroneckerDelta[k1 - q], 
{q,-\[Infinity], \[Infinity]}, {k,-\[Infinity],\[Infinity]}]
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: The output of the second example is correct, because MMA can not know if q==k or q !=k. However the problem is here:  if one sums over k1 and k, the output is not evaluated.

Comment: How can MMA not know that `q=k` in the second example since `KroneckerDelta[k - q]` is included?

Comment: Your are summing over k1 not k. If k != q the sum is zero.

Comment: true, so how can I make it understand that I want q==k and not q!=k ?

Comment: Simple, use k everywhere instead of q. (or the other way round)

Comment: This will not help me with my calculations. I am mentioning what I would like to achieve